# Objects are not valid as a React child found: object with keys {paddingTop, paddingBottom}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I am trying to style my `component` I am getting this error:

```
invariant.js?d8db:42 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {paddingTop, paddingBottom}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (created by Article)
    in div (created by Article)
    in Article (created by Articlelist)
    in div (created by Articlelist)
    in Articlelist (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
    at invariant (invariant.js?d8db:42)
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js?61bb:6748)
    at createChild (react-dom.development.js?61bb:7012)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js?61bb:7282)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js?61bb:7651)
    at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js?61bb:7756)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js?61bb:7747)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js?61bb:7998)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:8229)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:10224)
```

Here is my component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const styles = {
    article: {
        paddingBottom: 10,
        borderBottomStyle: 'solid',
        borderBottomColor: '#aaa',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    title: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    date: {
        fontSize: '0.8em',
        color: '#888',
    },
    author: {
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
    },
    body: {
        paddingLeft: 20,
    }
};
class Article extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={styles.article}>
                <div style={styles.title}>{this.props.article.title}</div>
                <div style={styles.date}>{this.props.article.date}</div>
                <div >style={styles.author}
                    <a  href={this.props.author.website}>
                        {this.props.author.firstName}-{this.props.author.lastName}
                    </a>

                </div>
                <div style={styles.body}>{this.props.article.body}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Article;
```

screenshot of my error:

[image]

Can I style my component like this? I know there is another way to style the component using `className`. But I don't want to use that method. Could you please tell me why I am getting this error?
Can I use this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing the `div` tag properly here:

```
<div >style={styles.author}
```

Because of this react consider `styles.author` as a child instead of `style`, which is not valid child.

Change it to

```
<div style={styles.author}>
```